# Is there a proper way to query ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, json

I am receiving the JSON from WebService and populating `ExpandoObject` from this one:

```
 var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
 var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
```

The JSON object is quite complex and in order to find the value I am doing this spaghetti code:

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> CountPair = new KeyValuePair<string, object>();

var currentCountPair = jsonObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "data").Value;

if (currentCountPair != null)
{
    currentCountPair = ((ExpandoObject)currentCountPair).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "children");

    if (currentCountPair != null)
    {
        currentCountPair = ((IList<object>)((KeyValuePair<string, object>)currentCountPair).Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentCountPair != null)
        {                                            
            currentCountPair = ((ExpandoObject)currentCountPair).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "data").Value;

            if (currentCountPair != null)
            {
                CountPair = ((ExpandoObject)currentCountPair).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "score");
                result.Score = CountPair.Value == null ? null : CountPair.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What do you think?  Is there any better way of getting that value from `ExpandoObject`?
Or at least to reduce the number of `if` statements and code complexity...

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't see any reason for using `ExpandoObject` in your code. The same result could be achieved with cleaner code using `JObject`s.

Second, what would help if you could express your query using “LINQ to null”. Basically, treat `null` as an empty collection and any other value as a collection containing just that value. (The technical term for this is [the Maybe monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad).)

With both of these changes, your code could look something like this:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

string result =
    from o in jsonObject.ToNullWrapper()
    from data in o["data"]
    from children in data["children"]
    from child in children.FirstOrDefault()
    from data2 in child["data"]
    from score in data2["score"]
    select score.ToString();
```

Note that (ab)using LINQ like this is not idiomatic and probably very confusing. But I think it results in very clean code.

To make this work, you need the implementation of LINQ to null:

```
public struct NullWrapper<T>
    where T : class
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public NullWrapper(T value)
        : this()
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(NullWrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.Value;
    }
}

public static class NullExtensions
{
    public static NullWrapper<T> ToNullWrapper<T>(this T value)
        where T : class
    {
        return new NullWrapper<T>(value);
    }

    public static NullWrapper<TResult>
        SelectMany<TSource, TIntermediary, TResult>(
        this NullWrapper<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TIntermediary> intermediarySelector,
        Func<TSource, TIntermediary, TResult> resultSelector)
        where TSource : class
        where TIntermediary : class
        where TResult : class
    {
        if (source.Value == null)
            return new NullWrapper<TResult>();

        var intermediary = intermediarySelector(source.Value);

        if (intermediary == null)
            return new NullWrapper<TResult>();

        return resultSelector(source.Value, intermediary).ToNullWrapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I think that the `SelectToken()` approach from my other answer is a much better solution in this case. But I thought I'll leave this here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ExpandoObject`, you can use `JObject` together with its `SelectToken()` method:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

var scoreToken = jsonObject.SelectToken("data.children[0].data.score");

string score = scoreToken == null ? null : scoreToken.ToString();
```